# Downloading file from url and saving to blob

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I have an azure function that downloads a file to a temporary file path and then saves the temp file to a blob. I have two questions:

1) Is there a way to manage the temporary files created by the function
Path.GetTempFileName(). i.e after the scope of the function delete the temp filename?

2) Is there a better practice for downloading files from a url to a blob?

```
var filename = Path.GetTempFileName();
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
myWebClient.DownloadFile(url, filename);
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filename))
{
    blob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: To delete the file, you can just use File.Delete() at the end of your Method. e.g. `File.Delete(filename);`  If it has to be done after the method is complete, then just save the filename off in a class level variable.

Comment: You can pass `myWebClient.OpenRead` directly to `blob.UploadFromStream`. No temp files are needed.

Comment: myWebClient.OpenRead worked

Answer (score 2):

Rather than downloading to the local file system, a more efficient approach would be to stream the URL contents directly to the blob stream. Something like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(dataStream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can directly perform server side copy from source URL via [CloudBlob.StartCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.startcopy?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlob_StartCopy_System_Uri_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_AccessCondition_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_AccessCondition_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_OperationContext_) instead of downloading and then downloading:

```
var account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(destinationContainer);
blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
var newBlockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(newFileName);
newBlockBlob.StartCopy(new Uri(sourceUrl));

// Monitor the copy state
while (true)
{
    newBlockBlob.FetchAttributes();
    Console.WriteLine("Copy state: {0}", newBlockBlob.CopyState);
    if (newBlockBlob.CopyState.Status != CopyStatus.Pending)
    {
        break;
    }

    Thread.Sleep(waitTime);
}
```